# Array.Prototype.Filter not removing an item which if found with includes()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to remove an item from an array.
There is a simple if check to determine if the item is added and if true, I am trying to use filter to remove it, but this is not working.
I do not understand how includes() can find the matching item but then when trying to filter it will not remove it?
The item in question is just a uuid.

```
const AddCheckedPriv = (PrivIdToAdd) => {
        if (newUser.privilege_groups.includes(PrivIdToAdd)) {
            console.log("includes");
            let newPrivilegeGroups = newUser.privilege_groups;
            newPrivilegeGroups.filter((priv) => priv != PrivIdToAdd);
            console.log(newPrivilegeGroups.find(PrivIdToAdd));
        } else {
            let newPrivilegeGroups = newUser.privilege_groups;
            newPrivilegeGroups = [...newPrivilegeGroups, PrivIdToAdd];
            setNewUser({ ...newUser, privilege_groups: newPrivilegeGroups });
        }
    };
```

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: `filter` method doesn't mutate the original array; it returns a new array with the items filtered out.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter` does not mutate the existing array in-place. (That'd be a problem in React, after all.) It returns a new array. You need to assign the result to a variable, or log the result, or something. Right now, you're just ignoring it.

```
if (newUser.privilege_groups.includes(PrivIdToAdd)) {
    let newPrivilegeGroups = newUser.privilege_groups.filter((priv) => priv !== PrivIdToAdd);
```

Comment: This is how I first had it setup but it causes the app to completely lock up??

Comment: There is nothing present in the code in your question that looks like it would result in the app locking up - the problem is elsewhere